# Qual è il senso di "folle" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel racconto *L'inseguimento* di Italo Calvino ho letto la frase seguente, che descrive i pensieri che ha il narratore mentre è in un ingorgo di traffico:

> Sono dunque i corpi a determinare lo spazio circostante, e se
>   quest'affermazione sembra in contrasto con l'esperienza tanto mia che del mio inseguitore - dato che noi due non riusciamo a determinare un bel niente, né spazio per fuggire né spazio per inseguire - è perché si tratta d'una proprietà non dei singoli
>   corpi ma di tutto l'insieme dei corpi nelle loro relazioni reciproche, nelle loro iniziative e indecisioni e messe in marcia, nei loro lampeggiamenti e strombettii e mordicchiamenti di unghie e continui rabbiosi strappi del cambio: *folle*, prima, seconda, *folle*; *folle*, prima, seconda, *folle*.

Qui "i corpi" sono le macchine intrappolate nell'ingorgo. Ho cercato la parola "folle" in alcuni dizionari, ma non capisco cosa possa significare in questa frase. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

È semplicemente la posizione del cambio che fa sì che il motore di un'automobile giri a vuoto e non sia in contatto con la trasmissione (significato 2.b [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/folle1/)). Qui descrive una guida concitata in mezzo al traffico in cui non si riesce mai ad andare oltre la seconda marcia e spesso si deve premere la frizione.

Comment: Quindi, è la posizione della leva del cambio corrispondente a quando nessuna marcia è messa. L'ho visto anche nel film *Italy in a day*, in una scena dove appare una ragazza che sta imparando a guidare.